# How to make a "Proxied-Hotspot"

Tags: proxy

I have an android phone running Kitkat. I am able to make a hotspot, however on every device that I connect it to I need a proxy to get it working. This could get a little annoying so is there maybe a way to create a hotspot that already has a proxy.

Comment: How are you making the hotspot on your first device? The default way doesn't add anything remotely related to proxy. On other devices, what proxy do you add into and how do you add into them?

Comment: @Firelord I am making the hotspot in settings on android device (or I  think what you meant by the "default way")

Comment: And the rest part of my comment?

Comment: @Firelord it doesn't have the proxy that I have added to the system with the hotspot. I use openvpn but mainly creating an apn with the proxy added to the fields required